serde-rs: deserialize enums with different content
I have a TOML file with lots of strings which are either plain strings (like a in the below example) or tables with translated strings (like b):
a = "Hi"
b = { en:"Hello", de:"Hallo" }

I want to deserialize those with Rust+Serde:
use serde::{self, Deserialize};

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct MultiLangString {
    de: Option<String>,
    en: Option<String>,
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
enum LangString {
    SingleLang(String),
    MultiLang(MultiLangString),
}

This does not work and serde returns this error:
Error {
    inner: Error {
        inner: TomlError {
            message: "wanted exactly 1 element, more than 1 element",
            raw: None,
            keys: ["feature", "title"],
            span: None
        }
    }
}

How do I deserialize such an enum where the variants have different content with Rust+serde?

Working Solution
Serde knows different ways to represent enums, documented here. The example TOML code in the question is an example of the untagged enum representation. Adding #[serde(untagged)] does the trick:
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct MultiLangString {
    de: Option<String>,
    en: Option<String>,
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
#[serde(untagged)]  // <-- this works
enum LangString {
    SingleLang(String),
    MultiLang(MultiLangString),
}


Not Working
Adding #[serde(flatten)] like so does not work because serde will refuse to recognize the flatten attribute on an enum:
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct MultiLangString {
    de: Option<String>,
    en: Option<String>,
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
enum LangString {
    SingleLang(String),
    #[serde(flatten)]  // <-- does not compile
    MultiLang(MultiLangString),
}



Why show a non-working solution?

I got stuck searching online for how to make #[serde(flatten)] work in this context but I could not find anything useful. I thus added it as a non-working attempt so that others who search for the same search terms around flatten can find the working solution.
